# Environment variable not set in container image after PUSH and PULL

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to see if we can find a way to persist env variables in images AFTER they are pulled from private docker registry. I have done the following steps

content of .env file

```
APP_DB_CACHE_UPDATE = 3600
```

content of docker-compose file

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      - APP_DB_CACHE_UPDATE=${APP_DB_CACHE_UPDATE}
```

command to build and check container and its env vars

```
$ APP_DB_CACHE_UPDATE=3602 docker-compose up
$ docker exec -it <container_id> printenv

APP_DB_CACHE_UPDATE=3602
```

then I

1. push  the image to private docker registry
2. I remove image from local machine
3. pull image from docker registry

```
$ docker tag app-name_app-name:latest  localhost:5000/app-name_app-name:latest
$ docker push localhost:5000/app-name_app-name:latest
$ docker rmi localhost:5000/app-name_app-name:latest
$ docker pull localhost:5000/app-name_app-name:latest
```

and now I check the enviorment after running this image, i am unable to see APP_DB_CACHE_UPDATE env variable

```
docker exec -it <new container image> printenv
```

Comment: You can build a new image based on the one you use and add a `ENV APP_DB_CACHE_UPDATE=3600` statement.

Comment: You can never change anything in an image after you initially build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker compose does not build images with env vars set through "environment" or "env_file". It builds images first, then provides the environment variables to the container runtime. See [environment](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment) specification:

> If your service specifies a build option, variables defined in
> environment are not automatically visible during the build.

Because of this, your image does not know about the environment variable specified in docker-compose file.

To set environment variables during/before the build, which will be persisted in the container after the image is built, you need to specify them in you build environment. You can do this in Dockerfile using ENV, for example:

```
ENV APP_DB_CACHE_UPDATE="3600"
```

See [Dockerfile ENV specification](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env).

> The environment variables set using ENV will persist when a container
> is run from the resulting image. You can view the values using docker
> inspect, and change them using docker run --env =

Then tell compose to use your Dockerfile with:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
```